# MySQL- Best practices for using rollback

Tags: mysql, rollback, dml

What is the best practice / recommended way of using ROLLBACK operation, if any DML operation fails ?

Any ROLLBACK, COMMIT mechanism ?

FYI: I'm using InnoDB tables which complies with Atomicity.

Comment: Depends entirely on each specific scenario. It sounds like you might want to look into SAVEPOINT for use in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways not to commit a transaction

- Explicit ROLLBACK
- Close a connection w/o COMMIT

Both of them are fine to use depending on what fits better the app logic.

*When to rollback explicitly?*

If you want to reuse a connection. If you want to make transactions as short as possible (a good thing to aim for).

*When to close the connect w/o commit?*

If a transaction is one-time task, and you'd like to simplify error handling.

Few things to consider.

- Do not keep uncommitted transactions for long time.  Often that happens when the app opens a trx, goes to do something else, comes back later to complete and commit the transaction. This really hurts. It leads to high CPU usage and kills performance.
- ROLLBACK usually goes into `except ...` block (or whatever applies to the specific language). But ROLLBACK itself may fail, so make sure to handle exceptions correctly to avoid "Failed to rollback a transaction" errors.
- ROLLBACK often takes more time than you'd expect. If transaction was large, the rollback takes more time than all the previous statements in the transaction. Make the transactions as short as possible.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
I understand, we can do it with programming language. But, how to achieve that within SQL ?
How to identify if any statement has failed within a transaction ? Then maybe based on the check we can either COMMIT or ROLLBACK using conditional statements.

Comment: it's not possible or I don't understand your request. From your app you send queries and get responses (query result, exceptions, etc). Based on that you proceed accordingly in your app. If you want something like `IF NOT UPDATE .. THEN ROLLBACK` then it's not supported by SQL itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for you reply. I wanted to achieve `IF NOT UPDATE .. THEN ROLLBACK` in SQL

Answer (score -1):

Rollback is not for any DML fails specifically, but it can used in situations like :

1. Data might be partially inserted due to transient state conflict/error.
2. Mistakenly injected data in your table.
3. Using Saving point + Rollback is to rollback if the data is not necessary for future from that specific (save) points.

Comment: Provided details are from own experiences,but still find the link found for you. Hope it might help you.                                                      https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm